# problems with displaying submenus with a timer

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javascript, so please bear with me.

I am working on creating a dropdown navigation menu, using a combination of html, css, and javascript (no JQuery).  Two links in the navigation bar have submenus that drop down onMouseover, and I am using setTimeout and clearTimeout to keep the submenus open until I move the mouse away.

Here is the problem that I am having.  If I hover over a link in the nav bar, I get its submenu, and it displays for as long as I keep the mouse there.  If I immediately move my mouse to the next link in the nav bar, I get that link's submenu, but only for the briefest instant before it disappears.  There is something in my timer settings that is contributing to this, but I am unable to locate it.  Can someone help me figure out which setting I need to change?

I realize that I may be too wordy here, and I apologize.  If you need me to clarify anything, please let me know.

Here is my javascript code.

```
function drop(menu) {
    if (menuId)
        menuId.style.display = 'none';

    menuId = document.getElementById(menu);
    menuId.style.display = 'block';
    menuId.style.position = 'relative';
    menuId.style.top = '100%';
    menuId.style.left = '0';

}

function beginTimer() {
    timer = window.setTimeout(hide, 500);
}

function timerToZero() {
    if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
}

function hide() {
    if (menuId)
        menuId.style.display = 'none';
}
```

My html code is here.  I have abbreviated the list items to show the relevant pieces.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="DepartmentMembers.html" onMouseover="drop('departmentMenu')" onMouseout="beginTimer()">Department Members</a>
        <ul id="departmentMenu" onMouseover = "timerToZero()" onMouseout = "beginTimer()" style="display:none;position:absolute">
            <li><a href="BrianKendricks.html">Brian Kendricks</a></li>
            <li><a href="TimJones.html">Tim Jones</a></li>
            <li><a href="DavidKline.html">David Kline</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="SystemsUsed.html" onMouseover="drop('systemMenu')" onMouseout="beginTimer()">Systems Used</a>
        <ul id="systemMenu" onMouseover = "timerToZero()" onMouseout = "beginTimer()" style="display:none;position:absolute">
            <li><a href="OrgChart.html">Organizational Chart of Library Systems</a></li>
            <li><a href="3M.html">3M Cloud (e-books)</a></li>
            <li><a href="Bibliotheca.html">Bibliotheca (DVD Checkout)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The rest of my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/donfrankrice/v870afc2/) can be found on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my problem! I ended up taking a look at the timer line

```
timer = window.setTimeout(hide, 500);
```

and I decided that I should try changing it to

```
timer = window.setTimeout(hide, 100);
```

That made a big difference for me!